# How do I make bash do vim-like tab completion for file names?

Tags: bash, vim, tab-completion

I'd like for bash to rotate through the matching file names instead of listing them, like the default tab completion behavior in vim. Is there an easy command to do this? This is essentially the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Map <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `menu-complete`.

In your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

Re-read the file to make it effective in the current shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

You can use the following command at a command prompt to enable the feature for the current session if you'd like to test it without editing the `~/.inputrc` file, for example.

```
bind '"\C-i" menu-complete'
```

Comment: Is there any way to make `SHIFT + TAB` go through the list in reverse?

Comment: @ubiquibacon: Generally speaking, in a terminal there's no difference between `Tab` and `Shift + Tab` (or other shifted vs. non-shifted control characters). However, you can use another keystroke to do the reverse stepping. `bind '"\C-q" "\e-\C-i"'` will cause `Ctrl + Q` to do this (or add `"\C-q" "\e-\C-i"` to your `~/.inputrc`. You may need to add `stty -ixon` to your `~/.bashrc` file to enable `Ctrl + Q` (and `Ctrl + S`). The `\e-` (Escape minus) is what reverses the direction.